# Converting battery powered LED lights to AC power

Tags: batteries, conversion

I have 8 LED decorative pieces that are powered by 4 AA batteries each. Each piece has a control board for different light patterns. Since it's expensive to operate these devices by replacing the batteries every few days, I was thinking of converting them to AC power. If my calculation is correct, when connected in series I would get a 48 volt power supply or if connected in parallel I could use a 6V power supply.

Comment: So what's the question then?

Comment: No, connect them in parallel to a 6 V source! Series connection is begging for problems.

Comment: Before you get too deep into cutting and soldering, consider using a "battery eliminator." That is, a set of fake batteries, with a connection to an external power supply. (See https://www.amazon.com/battery-eliminator/s?k=battery+eliminator)

Answer (score 2):

An AA battery has:

- Capacity of about 2000-2700 mAh depending on model, so if your lights last a few days, current draw must be less than 100mA, certainly less than 500mA.
- Voltage between 1.5V (fully charged) and 1V (almost discharged), so the lights must be designed to work between 4V and 6V, so they will work on 5V.

Therefore, I would recommend grabbing a cellphone "USB charger" from the junk pile (everyone has a ton of those thrown into a drawer somewhere), and cutting a USB cable. +5V is red, and 0V is black, connect to the corresponding places on your lights, just follow the wires from the battery holder.

If you use one "charger" to power several lights, they must be wired in parallel.

Comment: Wire color not guaranteed. Always measure.